# How do we link Dragonvale to Faceook?

Tags: dragonvale, facebook

I have two Kindle-fires for my grandchildren and they have a Dragonvale game on each.  My grandson lost his first 'park' (?) and had to restart.  We have two Facebook accounts but I cannot manage to link our Dragonvales to the Facebook accounts!

I do not see anything in options about Facebook -- I also do not see anyway to have 'friends' on our Dragonvales -- I have spent a lot of money on their games and they LOVE their dragons - where can we find out what to do!  Can we play DragonVale on Faebook?  the bigger screen would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was asked, so there have been some updates.

How to connect the game to Facebook:

Launch Dragonvale. Tap on Options at the bottom of the screen. In the Options menu, tap on "Login to Facebook." You will then be directed to login to Facebook. You will then receive a prompt asking if you want to continue playing your Local Park or Facebook, select Facebook. Your Dragonvale account should then be linked with Facebook.

Something to keep in mind:

If you receive an additional prompt after selecting Facebook, you likely will want to pick the higher level park (this will only happen if you have played Dragonvale with your Facebook account in the past.)

[Source](http://www.backflipstudios.com/help/amazon-device-faq/)